# How pass data from the child component (the child has its own state) to the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Expected effect: click button -> call function setEditing() -> call function item() inside setEditing() -> this.state.isEditing changes to true -> in parent this.state.isEdit changes to true. When I call the item () function, the value of isEditing does not change

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        isEdit = false; 
    };
  }

  handleSomething = (value) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        isEdit: value
      };
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                  handleSomething={this.handleSomething}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Todo**

```
class Todo extends Component {

  state = {
    isEditing: false
  }

  setEditing = () => {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
    })

    this.item();
  }

  item = () => { 
    const { isEditing} = this.state;
    this.props.handleSomething(isEditing);
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
        <button onClick={() => this.setEditing()}>Edit</button>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need the state to definitely have been updated before you call item, you need to use the second argument to setState.

Comment: code seems fine,I think issue must be in state have to made a console for isEditing and tried ?

Comment: I  checked in console.log. isEditing is always false

Comment: then the posted answer will do the trick `setEditing = () => {
  this.setState({
    isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
  },()=> this.item())
}`

Comment: Change this.state = {
        isEdit = false; 
    }; 
to 
 this.state = {
        isEdit : false 
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `this.item` after the state was changed, something like

```
setEditing = () => {
  this.setState({
    isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
  }, this.item)
}
```

Also, if you want to derive a new state form the old one, you'll have to use something like this:

```
setEditing = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isEditing: !prevState.isEditing
  }), this.item)
}
```

Comment: In function  `handleSomething` I have to change to `handleSomething = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        isEdit: value
    });
  }` ;  I don't need `prevState`?

Comment: @Umbro You don't need `prevState` there because the new state is not derived from the old one.

Comment: What is hidden under this `prevState`? How does it work underhood?

Comment: @Umbro You can find more details about that [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

Try basing your state change on the previous state, and call parent function in a callback :

```
setEditing = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isEditing: !prevState.isEditing
  }), this.item)
}
```

Because as written in the React doc :

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.
>   (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: In function handleSomething I have to change to handleSomething = (value) => { this.setState({ isEdit: value }); } ; I don't need prevState?

Comment: No, you have no need of it in this function, you could simply write `handleSomething = value => this.setState({ isEdit: value });`. Also check you state declaration in App component, you have a typo : change `isEdit = false;` to `isEdit: false;`

Comment: What is hidden under this `prevState`? How does it work underhood?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isEditing: false
  }

  setEditing = () => {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
    },this.item())
  }

  item = () => { 
    const { isEditing} = this.state;
    this.props.handleSomething(isEditing);
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
        <button onClick={() => this.setEditing()}>
          Edit
         </button>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        isEdit : false,
        todos : [
          "test 1",
          "test 2"
        ]
    };
  }

  handleSomething = (value) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        isEdit: value
      };
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                  handleSomething={this.handleSomething}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```